# Eliminating Duplicate records based on priority field - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

good morning. I do not think my head is thinking straight. I wrote the unions to get the following result set because I thought it might be easier this way to get the end value needed. Here nore there I can optimize this later. So I have the result set below. It's only in Excel so I could take a Screen Shot.

Table Schematic

Column A = EmployeeID

Column B = ActivityId

Column C = PriorityNumber

Column D = FSBillRate

Column E = Classification

[image: Result Set]

Anyways.. So if you norice (MD) Has a combo of A column and B Column twice .

MD Code:1

MD Code:1

But you notice that the first line has C column of 1 and the second line has C column of 3.

My Goal: To have only 1 combo of A and B Column based on column C. I want to keep the lower of the column C. So this case I would want to Keep 1. But in the case of BS code:1  4 and BS code:1 6 I would wan tto keep 4 obviously becasue 4 is lowwer than 6.

This must be accomplished in a SELECT statement as the data must remain and this is basically going to be a subquery to another query.

Comment: If your data is in Excel, why is this tagged "sql-server"?  Can you provide the definition of the table in the database?

Comment: Yes, My apologies. The data is not in excel as I explained I only copied the result set in excel so I could take a full screen shot. - Please see edited Schematic above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: 
(Edited to update column names based on comment)

Original answer using [Row_Number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```sql
with cte as (
  select [EmployeeID], [ActivityId], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]
    , rownumber= row_number() over (
        partition by [EmployeeID], [ActivityId]
        order by [Col3]
        )
  from [table]

)
  select [EmployeeID], [ActivityId], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]
    from cte
    where rownumber=1
```

Alternative solution using [Cross Apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```sql
select t.[EmployeeID], t.[ActivityId], x.[Col3], x.[Col4], x.[Col5]
  from [table] t
    cross apply (
      select top 1 i.[Col3], i.[Col4], i.[Col5] 
        from [table] i 
        where i.[EmployeeID] = t.[EmployeeID]
          and i.[ActivityId] = t.[ActivityId]
        order by x.[Col3]
          ) as x
  group by t.[EmployeeID], t.[ActivityId], x.[Col3], x.[Col4], x.[Col5]
```

Comment: SQLZim. This worked perfectly. However is there a way to do this with out using a with statement? Also, can you explain over and paritioning in simplistic terms. I very easily understood your schematic and design and tested it. However I would like to understand a little more of over partition.

Comment: The "with cte" is simply a derived table, which is a subquery with and alias.  If you don't want to use the with keyword, select from the subquery.  Remember to give it an alias.

Comment: I already took your code and modified it to run it on my end. But I did not want to use it as a with statement. So I simply emebeded it so I could use the rownumber as a column. Also, I was able to finally understand your code by watching the following video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFj-hZi8MKk

Comment: Thank you for leading me to my answer.